# Rewrite UDF to pandas UDF Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, user-defined-functions, pyspark-pandas

I have a dataframe:

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

sdf1 = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        (2022, 1, ["apple", "edible"]),
        (2022, 1, ["edible", "fruit"]),
        (2022, 1, ["orange", "sweet"]),
        (2022, 4, ["flowering ", "plant"]),
        (2022, 3, ["green", "kiwi"]),
        (2022, 3, ["kiwi", "fruit"]),
        (2022, 3, ["fruit", "popular"]),
        (2022, 3, ["yellow", "lemon"]),
    ],
    [
        "year",
        "id",
        "bigram",
    ],
)
sdf1.show(truncate=False)

    +----+---+-------------------+
    |year|id |bigram             |
    +----+---+-------------------+
    |2022|1  |[apple, edible]    |
    |2022|1  |[edible, fruit]    |
    |2022|1  |[orange, sweet]    |
    |2022|4  |[flowering , plant]|
    |2022|3  |[green, kiwi]      |
    |2022|3  |[kiwi, fruit]      |
    |2022|3  |[fruit, popular]   |
    |2022|3  |[yellow, lemon]    |
    +----+---+-------------------+
```

And i wrote a function that returns bigrams with the same last words in n-grams.I apply this function separately to the column.

```py
from networkx import DiGraph, dfs_labeled_edges

# Grouping
sdf = (
    sdf1.groupby("year", "id")
    .agg(F.collect_set("bigram").alias("collect_bigramm"))
    .withColumn("size", F.size("collect_bigramm"))
)

data_collect = sdf.collect()


@udf(returnType=ArrayType(StringType()))
def myfunc(lst):
    graph = DiGraph()

    for row in data_collect:
        if row["size"] > 1:
            for i, lst1 in enumerate(lst):
                while i < len(lst) - 1:
                    lst2 = lst[i + 1]
                    if lst1[0] == lst2[1]:
                        graph.add_edge(lst2[0], lst2[1])
                        graph.add_edge(lst1[0], lst1[1])
                    elif lst1[1] == lst2[0]:
                        graph.add_edge(lst1[0], lst1[1])
                        graph.add_edge(lst2[0], lst2[1])
                    i = i + 1

            gen = dfs_labeled_edges(graph)
            lst_tmp = []
            lst_res = []
            f = 0
            for g in list(gen):
                if (g[2] == "forward") and (g[0] != g[1]):
                    f = 1
                    lst_tmp.append(g[0])
                    lst_tmp.append(g[1])

                if g[2] == "nontree":
                    continue
                if g[2] == "reverse":
                    if f == 1:
                        lst_res.append(lst_tmp.copy())
                    f = 0
                    if g[0] in lst_tmp:
                        lst_tmp.remove(g[0])
                    if g[1] in lst_tmp:
                        lst_tmp.remove(g[1])

            if lst_res != []:
                lst_res = [
                    ii for n, ii in enumerate(lst_res[0]) if ii not in lst_res[0][:n]
                ]
            if lst_res == []:
                lst_res = None
            return lst_res


sdf_new = sdf.withColumn("new_col", myfunc(F.col("collect_bigramm")))
sdf_new.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----+-----------------------------+
|year|id |collect_bigramm                                                          |size|new_col                      |
+----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----+-----------------------------+
|2022|4  |[[flowering , plant]]                                            |1   |null                         |
|2022|1  |[[edible, fruit], [orange, sweet], [apple, edible]]              |3   |[apple, edible, fruit]       |
|2022|3  |[[yellow, lemon], [green, kiwi], [kiwi, fruit], [fruit, popular]]|4   |[green, kiwi, fruit, popular]|
+----+---+-----------------------------------------------------------------+----+-----------------------------+
```

But now i want to use the pandas udf. I would like to first groupby and get the `collect_bigramm`  column in the function. And thus leave all the columns in the dataframe, but also add a new one, which is the `lst_res` array in the function.

```py
schema2 = StructType(
    [
        StructField("year", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("id", IntegerType(), True),
        StructField("bigram", ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
        StructField("new_col", ArrayType(StringType(), True), True),
        StructField("collect_bigramm", ArrayType(ArrayType(StringType(), True), True), True),
    ]
)


@pandas_udf(schema2, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def myfunc(df):

    graph = DiGraph()
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        # Instead of the variable lst, i need to insert a column sdf['collect_bigramm']
        ...

    return df


sdf_new = sdf.groupby(["year", "id"]).apply(myfunc)
```

Comment: When grouping by `year` and `id`, you already collected `bigram` and returned `collect_bigramm `. Why are you expecting to return `bigram` as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You **don't** want to run `groupBy` twice (one for `sdf1` and one for `pandas_udf`), it'd simply kill the idea of "grouping a list of records then vectorize it then send to worker" of `pandas_udf`. You'd want to do something like this instead `sdf1.groupby("year", "id").applyInPandas(myfunc, schema2)`
2. Your UDF is now a "Panda UDF", which is literally just a Python function, take one Pandas DF and return another Pandas UDF. With that meaning, you can even run that function **without** Spark. The trick here is just how to form your dataframe to feed with what you need. Check the running code below, I kept most of your networkx code, just fix a little from the input and output.

```py
def myfunc(pdf):
    pdf = (pdf
        .groupby(['year', 'id'])['bigram']
        .agg(list=list, len=len) # you might want to fix the list here to set
        .reset_index()
        .rename(columns={
            'list': 'collect_bigram',
            'len': 'size',
        })
    )

    graph = DiGraph()
    if pdf['size'][0] > 1:
        lst = pdf['collect_bigram'][0]
        for i, lst1 in enumerate(lst):
        ... # same as original code
        if lst_res == []:
            lst_res = None
        pdf['new_col'] = [lst_res]
    else:
        pdf['new_col'] = None
    return pdf
```